What movie help!
I can't for the life of me remember this movie or more than two scenes from it there are two girls one boy and older guy in a car. Two scenes I can distinctly remember is one where the girl is driving and the guy is sleeping in the passenger seat and she tries to get his wedding ring off without waking him up. The other scene is where the boy falls asleep in the backseat with the girl and drools on her boob with the older guy asking if he quote on quote did it

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title . See our [help/on-topic]  page.

it's your lucky day because I actually remember that scene also. The movie is about a teen and his mother's boyfriend whom he doesn't like. So mother's boyfriend picks him up from the school away and they must travel home, hoping they will get to know each other so the boy will accept him. I actually remember that one of the girls, I think the one with the drooling is Ari Meyers, and then it wasn't hard to find the movie:
Dutch (1991)
I remember the guy wearing the ring on little finger that he has to remove before fist fight, otherwise he would hurt someone too much or something like that.

Seriously my hero. I saw this when I was just a kid and have been trying to remeber it for ever. Thanks!

Gotta love this board.  People come here to seek answers, provide all the info they can remember, it is deemed "not enough info" and downvoted... yet someone comes up with the correct answer and is also downvoted, then the question is put on hold or ultimately closed.  So we have an answered question and correct answer with nothing but downvotes.
